# Serialize list of interface types with ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack

I'm looking at ways to introduce something other than BinaryFormatter serialization into my app to eventually work with Redis. ServiceStack JSON is what I would like to use, but can it do what I need with interfaces?
It can serialize (by inserting custom __type attribute)

```
public IAsset Content;
```

but not

```
public List<IAsset> Contents;
```

- the list comes up empty in serialized data. Is there any way to do this - serialize a list of interface types?

The app is big and old and the shape of objects it uses is probably not going to be allowed to change.
Thanks

Comment: Can you include a complete sample code of what doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from http://www.servicestack.net/docs/framework/release-notes

You probably don't have to do much :)

> The JSON and JSV Text serializers now support serializing and
>   deserializing DTOs with Interface / Abstract or object types. Amongst
>   other things, this allows you to have an IInterface property which
>   when serialized will include its concrete type information in a __type
>   property field (similar to other JSON serializers) which when
>   serialized populates an instance of that concrete type (provided it
>   exists).
>
> [...]
>
> Note: This feature is automatically added to all
>   Abstract/Interface/Object types, i.e. you don't need to include any
>   [KnownType] attributes to take advantage of it.

By not much:

```
public interface IAsset
{
    string Bling { get; set; }
}

public class AAsset : IAsset
{
    public string Bling { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "A" + Bling;
    }
}

public class BAsset : IAsset
{
    public string Bling { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "B" + Bling;
    }
}

public class AssetBag
{
    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]
    public List<IAsset> Assets { get; set; } 
}

class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var bag = new AssetBag
                {
                    Assets = new List<IAsset> {new AAsset {Bling = "Oho"}, new BAsset() {Bling = "Aha"}}
                };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bag, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });
            var anotherBag = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AssetBag>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I wrote in my question? It works for a single IInterface property, but not for a property which is a list of IInterface objects, and I need the latter